# Fatal error: Class 'Logs' not found in

Tags: php

I'm going crazy over these past few days and I really need your help because I don't know what else to do. I tried everything.

Here is the problem:
I have two files. `site.php` and `logs.php`.

Here is the content of `logs.php`:

```
class Logs {

    function __construct() {

    }

}
```

Now comes the fun part, beginning of 'site.php':

```
require_once("database.php");
require_once("logs.php");

class Site {

    private $db;
    private $logs;

    function __construct() {

        $this->logs = new Logs(); ### this is the error line
        $this->db = new MySQLDatabase();

    }

}
```

They are all in the same directory. Why can't it find my class?

Comment: why is logs.php written with two differenet `g` s?

Comment: `logs.php` has the `<?php` tag?

Comment: yes, both has <?php tag

Comment: @phpNoOb Different fonts for default text and code blocks?!!!

Comment: add a die statement to the top of logs.php so you can confirm the the correct file is being included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping. I have found out what the problem was! Turns out, for some reason I shouldn't name my php file 'logs.php'. As soon as I renamed it, it works perfectly. I have no idea why but it just wont work with that name.

Answer (score 1):

PHP might be including the wrong the file.  PHP will search the include path before looking inside the script's directory. You may somehow have a logs.php in your include path (See [This PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for details.)  I suggest maybe adding an echo "hello world"; in the root of your logs.php.

You might also have accidentally enclosed the class inside another class or function.  Make sure the class is only inside the  tags.